# JSON Body for "AddUserTargets" Patch Request

Tags: launchdarkly

I'm attempting to patch a feature flag via the API, adding an individual target to the flag following the documentation [for patching feature flags](https://apidocs.launchdarkly.com/tag/Feature-flags#operation/patchFeatureFlag).

Targeting an API route of
https://app.launchdarkly.com/api/v2/flags/foo/bar

Where bar is a boolean flag, I'm using the body:

```
{
    "instructions":[{"kind": "addUserTargets", "values":["foo@bar.com"],"variationId": "True"}],
    "environmentKey": "development"
}
```

I am receiving a return of

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my request body? I haven't been able to find the variationId through the Darkly UI

Edit: Proof of Proper Headers -
[image]

Comment: Is `True` a valid variation ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it further, it appears that you are in fact missing the variation ID on the flag you are attempting to patch, which is a required field.

You would need to make a request to gather that data as described [here](https://apidocs.launchdarkly.com/tag/Feature-flags#operation/getFeatureFlag) and then modify your request accordingly.

Comment: Correct. It seems that the variationId GUID is unavailable through the Darkly UI.